# Triangulation in Stereo-Vision?

Tags: stereo-vision

I need some help in 3D Positioning system I'm trying to set up.

At the moment I am using 2 Calibrated cameras, my strategy is to place an AR Marker on the scene, identify the position of the AR Marker in the two different (left & right) images, and then triangulate the point to get the 3D coordinates.

Another approach I have is to project laser stripes on the scene, use the coordinates of the intersection of the laser points for triangulation. So I feel that if I calculate this intersection based on just images the performance difference will not be so much from using an AR marker, because ultimately we would be just using images to extract our feature. So I feel like one must calibrate the laser with the camera in order to get some real benefit of the geometry - not sure. I am a little confused. Any ideas?

I guess in general my question is - how do we benefit from the laser? My intuition was that laser helps in identifying a feature on the scene easily, so it reduces the correspondence search - but we can say the same for an AR Marker, so in what other way can we benefit from using a laser? (Geometric constraint, or something?)